# Why do non believers hate being confronted with the truth?

Tags: life-of-jesus, atheism, non-christians

As I understand the bible those who do not accept Jesus into their hearts go to hell. I understand it's more than just being a "christian", you actually have to have this relationship with god. And you'd think people would be happy when you tell them that Jesus loves them and that, without him they'd never be able to experience a love like his love, but it would appear nearly all of them think you're some sort of idiot, some will even go as far as to make a mockery out of you. How do you deal with this?

And I understand it's a choice but I feel the need to help these people find Jesus in their lives. But it's difficult when there's that one person who goes on the defensive.

Comment: People are evil sinners and their default reaction is to mock the Gospel. People don't want to be saved. People prefer Hell to Heaven (although they wouldn't if they actually stopped to think about it for a few seconds...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesus answered that question for you:

> Mark 6:11  And whoever will not receive you nor hear you, when you depart from there, shake off the dust under your feet as a testimony against them. Assuredly, I say to you, it will be more tolerable for Sodom and Gomorrah in the day of judgment than for that city!"

God himself will not interfere with man's free will, otherwise we would all still be in the garden of Eden. Each man or woman chooses their own destiny. And that is just how God wants it to be.

There is an ongoing argument about predestination, and whether God created some people as fodder for the fire, but according to Jesus that was not God's intent.

> Matthew 18:14  Even so it is not the will of your Father who is in heaven that one of these little ones should perish.

Jesus gave us the Great commission which is to preach the word to all the Nations, not to force salvation onto anyone.